# Add telemetry keys and error message to Azure App Insights using HTTP query

Tags: azure, http, logging, azure-application-insights, rest

How to add a log with an error message and telemetry keys to the Azure Application Insights service using the HTTP query?

This is a C# code example that logging messages with telemetry keys to App Insights.

```
var keys = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    { TelemetryKeysNames.Application, configuration.Value.Title },
    { TelemetryKeysNames.User, context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name }
};

using (logger.BeginScope(keys))
{
    logger.Log(logLevel, ex, message, args);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "add a log with an error message"? Or do you mean that you want to send an error message with telemetry keys(is it custom properties for telemetry keys)?

Comment: Yes, I mean that I want to send to App Insights error messages with custom properties.

Comment: hi, is it a web project, or console project?

Comment: Hi, it is a Data Factory`s Web activity.

Comment: I want to confirm that can you see any telemetry data are sent to application insights?

Comment: The code example adds new custom properties to app insights, this is a code from an Asp.net core 3.1 service and it works fine, but the main purpose is to send Azure Data Factory`s errors to app insights using a Web activity that can execute HTTP queries. The problem is that I can not find a query example.

Comment: what do you mean "The problem is that I can not find a query example."? Do you want to query the errors from application insights via code?

Comment: I mean that I can not found any example of an HTTP query that writes logs to app insights with custom properties.

Comment: For the HTTP query, is that something like using httpclient and post requests to write these logs?

Comment: HTTP query is a simple query string like "https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps//metrics/undefined", it is not an HTTP client.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216916/discussion-between-ivan-yang-and-igorrogachov).